# fetch most recent non null record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to fetch the most recent record and find a non-`NULL` match. The problem is my subquery returns more than one result.

**Data set**

```
| ID |         DD | SIG_ID |      DCRP |
----------------------------------------
|  1 | 2010-06-01 |      1 |    Expert |
|  2 | 2010-09-01 |      1 |    Expert |
|  3 | 2010-12-01 |      1 |    Expert |
|  4 | 2010-12-01 |      1 | Expert II |
|  5 | 2011-03-01 |      1 | Expert II |
|  6 | 2011-06-01 |      1 |    (null) |
|  7 | 2010-06-01 |      2 |    Senior |
|  8 | 2010-09-01 |      2 |    Senior |
|  9 | 2010-09-01 |      2 |    Senior |
| 10 | 2010-12-01 |      2 | Senior II |
| 11 | 2011-03-01 |      2 |    (null) |
| 12 | 2011-03-01 |      2 |    Senior |
| 13 | 2010-06-01 |      3 |    (null) |
| 14 | 2010-09-01 |      3 |    (null) |
| 15 | 2010-12-01 |      3 |    (null) |
```

**Query**

```
SELECT a.sig_id, a.id, 
  CASE
    WHEN b.dcrp IS NULL
      THEN
        (SELECT dcrp
         FROM tbl
         WHERE sig_id = a.sig_id
           AND id < a.id
           AND dcrp IS NOT NULL)
      ELSE b.dcrp
  END AS dcrp
FROM
  (SELECT sig_id, MAX(id) id
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY sig_id) a
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id, dcrp
   FROM tbl
   WHERE dcrp IS NOT NULL) b ON b.id = a.id
```

**Desired result**

Fetch the most recent `dcrp` for each `sig_id`:

```
| ID |         DD | SIG_ID |      DCRP |
----------------------------------------
|  5 | 2011-03-01 |      1 | Expert II |
| 12 | 2011-03-01 |      2 |    Senior |
| 15 | 2010-12-01 |      3 |    (null) |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98421/6)

Comment: Most recent per `sig_ID`?

Comment: @ypercube Correct. Just updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SIG_ID 
                                ORDER BY CASE WHEN DCRP IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                                DD DESC) RN
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

And the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98421/20).

Answer (score 2):

```
;with si as (
  select distinct sig_id from tbl
)

select * 
from si
cross apply (select top 1 * from tbl where si.sig_id=tbl.sig_id order by case when dcrp is null then 1 else 0 end asc,dd desc) sii
```

and with fiddler :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e267/2/0

Comment: This gives the correct results, but the distinct + cross apply yields a much more expensive plan than the row_number variations.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're too damn knowledgeable.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk bwahaha I think you must have me confused with someone else. :-)

Answer (score -2):

The query in SQLFiddle fails due to subquery returning more than 1 row.
Adding `TOP 1` fixes that. Please check if it is OK.

```
THEN
        (SELECT TOP 1 dcrp
         FROM tbl
         WHERE sig_id = a.sig_id
           AND id < a.id
           AND dcrp IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: When downvoting, please explain the reason. I don't mind deleting the answer.